# dynamically change the color for every line in textarea and panel using flex 4 and action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have created a simple text chat application for android device using flex 4 and action script 3. in the text chat I have given a option for change font color. I have used "TextInput" for enter text message and "Textarea" for shows the chat messages. when I change the color of the text, all the lines in the "textarea" color has been changing.

```
textoutput.setStyle("color",textInput.getStyle("color"));
textoutput.text += userNameInput.text + ": " + msg + "\n";"
```

this is the code I have used. but I need to change the color for every line in the "textarea".
In the other hand, i have created the panel for display chat, and dynamically created the label for the message and dynamically I have changed the color but all the lines are merging in same line. I need to add line break for every dynamic label in the panel window.

```
var mylabel:Label=new Label();
mylabel.setStyle("color",textInput.getStyle("color"));
mylabel.text += userNameInput.text + ": " + msg +      "\n";
        panelId.addElement(mylabel);"
```

this is the code I have used for adding dynamic label into Panel . can any one kindly suggest me some idea for solving any one of this problem means that should be very helpful for me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some info that might be helpful , from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS8d7bb3e8da6fb92f-20050207122bd5f80cb-7ff5.html

Formatting ranges of text within a text field

A useful method of the flash.text.TextField class is the setTextFormat() method. Using setTextFormat(), you can assign specific properties to the contents of a part of a text field to respond to user input, such as forms that need to remind users that certain entries are required or to change the emphasis of a subsection of a passage of text within a text field as a user selects parts of the text.

The following example uses TextField.setTextFormat() on a range of characters to change the appearance of part of the content of myTextField when the user clicks the text field:

```
var myTextField:TextField = new TextField(); 
myTextField.text = "No matter where you click on this text field the TEXT IN ALL CAPS changes format."; 
myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT; 
addChild(myTextField); 
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeText); 
var myformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
myformat.color = 0xFF0000; 
myformat.size = 18; 
myformat.underline = true; 

function changeText(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 

 myTextField.setTextFormat(myformat, 49, 65); 
}
```